# Terraform: Iterate over a list of strings in a nested JSON with terraform-provider-aci

Tags: terraform, cisco

I am having problems with this issue for to long. I am trying to set up some Infrastructure with Terraform and Cisco ACI. What I want to do now is to set up multiple epgs for one tenant. So with for_each iam iterating over my JSON. But I don't get it how I can iterate over the epg key (which contains a list of strings). It can't be that hard! But I don't get it.

#### First of all my .json

```
{
   "tenants": [
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "kde0815",
   "bd": "bd0815",
   "vRF": "vrf0815",
   "epg": [
      "epg1"
   ],
   "_fwdCtrl": "disabled",
   "_isAttrBasedEPg": "no",
   "_matchT": "no",
   "_prefGrMemb": "unenforced"
},
 {
   "id": 97,
   "name": "kde0816",
   "bd": [
      "bd0816"  
   ],
   "vRF": "vrf0816",
   "epg": [
      "epg1",
      "epg2,
      "epg3,
      "epg4" 
   ],
   "_fwdCtrl": "disabled",
   "_isAttrBasedEPg": "no",
   "_matchT": "no",
   "_prefGrMemb": "unenforced"
}
]
}
```

#### my resources.tf

```
locals {
  # get json 
  user_data = jsondecode(file("./data/aci-data_test.json"))

  # get all users
  all_users = [for tenants in local.user_data.tenants : tenants.name]

}

resource "aci_application_epg" "epgLocalName" {
  for_each               = { for inst in local.user_data.tenants : inst.id => inst }
  relation_fv_rs_bd      = aci_bridge_domain.bdLocalName[each.value.id].id
  application_profile_dn = aci_application_profile.apLocalName[each.value.id].id
  
  # dynamic "name" {
  #   for_each = each.value.epg 
  #   content {
  #     name = name.value
  #   }
  #}

}
```

of course this is not all of my code. I´ve created Tenants, Bridgedomains and so on already.
I tried to use the dynamic block to go over the "epg" two errors occurred

```
Error: Missing required argument
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found
```

```
Error: Unsupported block type
│ Blocks of type "name" are not expected here.
```

so I tired to use a second for_each loop

```
Error: Attribute redefined: The argument "for_each" was already set at resources.tf:54,3-11. Each argument may be set only once.
```

so far I understood you use for-loops only for modifying/filtering... strings. Is there a way just to use the for loop to pass the string to the variable "name" in the `aci_applicaton_profile`?

I am really stuck with Terraform here... never had problems with Python doing this.
So if you have any idea I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve here. For one, the `name` argument is required, but I don't think you can set it dynamically then and it's not of a block type anyway.  There is also a `name` in your JSON data, why not use that?

Comment: So actually I want to use a nested loop in my resource "aci_application_epg". So that i can iterate over my epg list to use every entry in this list as the name for the epg. 

Writing this I am realizing my problem... What Iam trying here ist to add multiple names for one epg. But I need multiple epgs. I need to rethink this and my .json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your `user_data`. For example:

```
locals {
 
  flat_all_users = merge([ for id, inst in local.user_data.tenants:
          {
            for epg in inst.epg:
              "${id}-${epg}" => {
                    id = id
                    name = epg
              }
          }    
    ]...)
}
```

then

```
resource "aci_application_epg" "epgLocalName" {
  for_each               = localflat_all_users
  relation_fv_rs_bd      = aci_bridge_domain.bdLocalName[each.value.id].id
  application_profile_dn = aci_application_profile.apLocalName[each.value.id].id
  name                   = each.value.name
}
```

Comment: Okai I guess this will work for me! I was thinking to use different .jsons now, but this looks way better. Thanks!